# table ESPUMA.ORDER_DETAILS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: oracle, triggers, database-trigger

I have 3 tables with the following columns :

> `PRODUCTS(product_id,image, name,price,create_date)` `ORDERS(order_id,amount,customerAddress,email,customerName,phone,orderDate,orderNum)`
>   `ORDER_DETAILS(id,amount,price,quantity,order_id,product_id)`

I created a new table called `PRODUCTS_SOLD(product_id, quantity)` and a trigger called `PRODUCTS_TRIGGER` so after each insert on `ORDER_DETAILS`, the product_id and quantity of each product will be inserted on table `PRODUCTS_SOLD`.

This is the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PRODUCTS_TRIGGER 
AFTER INSERT ON ORDER_DETAILS 
FOR EACH ROW 
  DECLARE
  ID order_details.product_id%type := :NEW.PRODUCT_ID; 
  product_quantity number;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(quantity) INTO product_quantity FROM ORDER_DETAILS 
  WHERE product_id = ID;
  INSERT INTO PRODUCTS_SOLD VALUES(ID,product_quantity);
END;
```

> It shows this error:
>
> ```
> ORA-04091: table ESPUMA.ORDER_DETAILS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
> ```
>
> What can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> Just convert your trigger to `BEFORE INSERT` from `AFTER INSERT`.

Since it's struggling with determining the sum of quantity by `:NEW.PRODUCT_ID` of `ORDER_DETAILS` table during the DML operation for the same table.